# why v-for does not render all objects?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

i'm trying to display search result that i'm getting it from api. but v-for does not render all objects?

this is my search-box:

[image]

as you see there is just one item, but every thing is right in vue dev tools:

[image]

and this is vue component (v-for):

[image]

and this is dom result:

[image]

whats wrong?

this is data:
[image]

Comment: It is impossible to know without viewing the code that declares and updates the `result`. However, I would bet that `result` is an array and you're pushing items to it after the api call via `Array.push`  or the likes, which may be messing with the Vue reactivity system: https://vuejs.org/2016/02/06/common-gotchas/#Why-isn%E2%80%99t-the-DOM-updating

Comment: Your v-for is ok, so please show us data of each child object in your result object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value in `result` is an object and not an array. While it is possible to iterate over an object using `v-for` it seems unlikely that this is what you want here. Your object has the properties `"0"`, `"1"`, `"2"`, `"3"` and `"ok"`. All 5 of these will be included in the `v-for`, which is why you have 5 `<li>` elements being generated.

Try changing your code to the following to get a better understanding of what's going on:

```html
<li v-for="(item, index) in result" :key="index">
    index: {{ index }}
    <br><br>
    item: {{ item }}
</li>
```

I would suggest changing the format you use for `result` to put the results themselves inside an array, separate from the `"ok"` property. So your server might return something like `{"ok": true, "results": [...]}` and you could then pluck out the `"results"` property and throw away the rest.

There is a further problem. In your original data you have a typo in several of your data entries. The property `"link;"` should be called `"link"`. Note the extra `;` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Array object might be null or blank.

> Blockquote

```html
<div class="category-list" v-for="category in categories">
    <router-link :to="{{category.name}}" class="dropdown-item">{{category.text}}</router-link>
</div>
```

if you are getting still error please send me object which are get in array.